# How to search from a specific file in a csv. database excel

Tags: python, excel, csv

I'm creating an address book program and I came accross the problem that even if the user searched by surname. They could enter a forename and still be printed contact info. How can I restrict the csv search to only the one column.

My code:

```
if choice == 'surname':
    print()
    surname = input('Input surname: ')
    print()
    with open('AddressBook.csv', newline='') as myfile:
        reader = csv.reader(myfile)
        for row in reader:
            if surname in row:
                print(row)
            else:
                ()
```

Addressbook in question (no real contact info):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLcmi.png

Comment: `if surname == row.split(",")[0]` just check against the first column

Comment: It says "invalid syntax" after the [0]

Answer (score 0):

When iterating over `csv.reader(myfile)`, you will get a list of all values in the row. So, all you need to do is change `if surname in row:` to `if surname == row[0]:`.

However, to be more defensive and account for blank lines, you may want to consider having `if row and surname == row[0]:`